# Program “python” is not found in PATH

Tags: android, python, c++, eclipse, cocos2d-x

I've been trying to open a Cocos 2d-x project in Eclipse. The project is a C++ project, and the builder is a python script. After opening it, I get an error "Program “python” is not found in PATH."

I've done some searching, and everyone who has experienced this issue has said that adding python to the build environment solved the issue. I tried that, and it didn't work. (I also tried restarting eclipse after the change, still no effect)

Most of the image below shows that I have python in my build environment, and the very bottom shows the error I get.

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

[image: SS]

Comment: Did you install Python?

Comment: Yes. It is located at C:/Python27

Comment: Did you add it to your PATH in System Control Panel? right click My Computer->Properties->Advanced->Environment Variables->System Variables->Path->Edit

Comment: I didn't add it myself, but it is listed there.

Comment: Here is an image of Python listed in my system variables. [image](http://imgur.com/cr6OqMJ)

Comment: You need to include the path to Python in your `PATH` environment variable not just in a stand alone `PYTHON` variable.