# Keep getting "Program python is not found in PATH"

Tags: android, python, c++, python-2.7, cocos2d-x

I've been trying to create the cocod2dx environment for android in my windows 8.1  os

I'm following all instructions I found online, when I finally get to open the project on eclipse I am getting the error below:

[image]

I've tried to setup the os environment variables like described here 
[Program “python” is not found in PATH](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24743446/program-python-is-not-found-in-path)

but still not success (I restart the computer after any environment variable changes)

[image]

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`C:\Python27\Python.exe` points to a file (python.exe) but you are supposed to provide paths to a folder.

Try using `C:\Python27` in the *Edit System Variable* dialog.